# I have 2 different login pages on one website and I want to redirected them to a different pages

Tags: authentication, redirect

I have 2 different login pages on one website and I want to redirected them to a different pages.

For Example:

abc.com/login want to redirect after successful login on page abc.com/dashboard.
abc.com/wp-login want to redirect after successful login on page abc.com/drumtif.
Is that possible I need your help.